# Refraction and transparency?

Tags: directx11

I need to do some refraction in a sphere. Do I need to make the object transparent first? Or just use refraction(refract) in HLSL DirectX?

Comment: [Generic Refraction Simulation](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter19.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not supposed to make the object use transparent blending, instead, you should blend its color with the refracted scene color in its shader when rendering the object.